# Uploading multiple images for single record in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

As questioned above I want to upload multiple images for single product into database table (table will contain only image paths).

My code is:

Controller - `productController.php`

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->model('productModel');
}
public function index()
{
    $data['product_list'] = $this->productModel->get_all_products();
    $this->load->view('productDisplay', $data);
}
public function add_form()
{
    $this->load->view('insertProduct');
}
private function setup_upload_option()
{
    $config = array();
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploadProductImages/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|gif|jpeg';
    $config['encrypt_type'] = true;
    $config['overwrite'] = false;
    return $config;
}
public function insert_new_product()
{
    $this->load->library('upload');
    $files = $_FILES;
    $count = count($_FILES['images']['name']);
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
    {
        $_FILES['images']['name'] = $files['images']['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['images']['type'] = $files['images']['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'] = $files['images']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['images']['size'] = $files['images']['size'][$i];
        $_FILES['images']['error'] = $files['images']['error'][$i];

        $this->upload->initialize($this->setup_upload_option());
        if($this->upload->do_upload() == false)
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->load->view('insertProduct', $error);
        }
        else
        {
            $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
            $udata['name'] = $this->input->post('name');
            $udata['manufacturer'] = $this->input->post('manufacturer');
            $udata['price'] = $this->input->post('price');
            $udata['images'] = $upload_data['file_name'];
            $res = $this->productModel->insert_products_to_db($udata);
            if($res)
            {
                header('location:'.base_url()."index.php/productController/".$this->index());
            }
        }
    }
```

Model - `productModel.php`

```
public function insert_products_to_db($data)
{
    return $this->db->insert('product_info', $data);
}
```

View - `insertProduct.php`

```
<?php if(isset($error)){echo $error;}?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/productController/insert_new_product" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table >
    <tr>
        <th >Product Name</th>
        <td ><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th >Manufacturer</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="manufacturer" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th >Price</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="price"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th >Images</th>
        <td><input type="file" name="images[]" multiple=""/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th >&nbsp;</th>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

My database table contains 5 fields p_id, name, manufacturer,price and images. And after running this code, when I clicks on Add it do not show any error or do not redirect to controller but it stays on same page and no any image is present in `uploadProductImages` and also no new product will insert in database table.

Any help for this new learner will be appreciated.

Comment: Change this `$count = count($_FILES['images']['name']);` to `$count = count($files['images']['name']);` Because you assign `$files = $_FILES;`

Comment: Yes, changed but still not doing any action. It stays on same `insertProduct.php`

Comment: Post your full code of `insertProduct.php` file

Comment: @Saty please see my newly edited question, I think problem is at else loop part of code i.e. ` $upload_data = $this->upload->data();`

Comment: how can you save multiple images???

Comment: check https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/examples.html#query-builder-insert how to insert data using array

Comment: is your image save physically in folder? what is the value of this? $upload_data

Comment: yes , but i don't know details, I developed this by watching tutorial. I think there is problem with my `for loop`. I require to insert only one record for one product along with multiple images